# falcor: Subscribe to model changes?

Tags: falcor

Is it possible to subscribe to model changes, i.e. suppose I want to `get('todos[0]["completed"]').subscribe(//render function)` and after `setValue('todos[0]["completed"]', true)` model emits new data and render function is invoked with this new data?

I tried the exact same approach as described, but for some reason render function is not invoked after setValue

Answer (score 3):

It is currently not possible, nor is there any plans for observation at this level.

It is possible to be notified when *something* changes.  If you use a reducer style `function shouldUpdate(previousProps, nextProps) { ... }` you can use the `getVersion` function at each level to only render what is needed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a reference to a GitHub issue for where these plans were made?

While I recognize there would be significant complexity to add this functionality, it would increase the attractiveness of Falcor a great deal IMO.

Comment: There surely is going to be.  Satyen D (on the githubs) has taken over a lot of the responsibility and will be producing roadmaps, answering questions, etc. etc.  If you would like to ping github you should get a response in a reasonable amount of time.